# How to display HTML <FORM> as inline element next to images?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have some images, with one of them being able to submit a hidden form.

My problem is that I need all the images to display inline with each other. The image with the form submit refuses to do this.

The code, basically, is this:

```
  <img class="inline" src="image.png" />
  <img class="inline" src="image2.png" />
  <img class="inline" src="image3.png" />

<form action="/forms/important-form.php" method="POST">
 <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="infoForForm" VALUE="Information">
 <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="URL" VALUE="/employee-xyz76r3-headshot.png">
 <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="employeeTitle" VALUE="Salesperson" >
 <input type="image" class="inline" src="email.png" alt="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

CSS like this:

```
 .inline {
  display: inline!important;
  float: right;
}
```

Definitely not working though. The image that functions to submit the hidden form (the email icon) refuses to stay inline.

[image: Showing that the images will not display inline]

Thank you for all of your help! Any ideas/solutions are appreciated.

P.S. Just try to ignore that Chief Marketing Officer is misspelled haha.

Comment: What kind of `HTML` is `<input type="image" class="inline" src="email.png" alt="Submit Form" />`? I heard of `img` tag.

Comment: try wrapping the images around a `div` floated right

Comment: @VedantTerkar off the w3 website http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1

Comment: @cr0ss ok I'll try right now!

Comment: @cr0ss awesome, that worked!! write that as an answer if you want it confirmed as the official answer & you get more points for your account

Comment: I know it is unpopular as a solution, but what about a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that a `form` element is a block element by default. To change this, making the images appear on the same line, only the following CSS rule is needed:

```
form { display: inline }
```

Well, you also need to change `href` attributes in `img` elements to `src` attributes, but without this fix, the first three images do not display at all.

You don’t need anything else, since `img` elements are inline by default.

You don’t need even that single CSS rule if you move the `img` elements inside the `form` element.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the images around a `div` floated right.

Answer (score 1):

You have to float images too. And `display: inline` do nothing there, all floating elements are `block`ed.